# Custom multidimensional object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Guys can you help with this customization of objects. I want to index the object properly but the current output of the object is that the index is the id of the store.

**Sample Object**

```
var stocks = [
{
    "size": "2",
    "count": 5,
    "store": {
       "id": 3,
       "title": "Belconnen"
    }
},
{
    "size": "3",
    "count": 4,
    "store": {
       "id": 4,
       "title": "Canberra"
    }
},
{
    "size": "4",
    "count": 4,
    "store": {
       "id": 5,
       "title": "Bankstown"
    }
},
{
    "size": "5",
    "count": 5,
    "store": {
       "id": 4,
       "title": "Canberra"
    }
}];
```

**Current Output**

```
{
  0: {
      "sizes": {
                 2: 3, 
                 3: 0, 
                 4: 0, 
                 5: 0
               }
     }
},
{
  1: {
      "sizes": {
                 2: 0, 
                 3: 3, 
                 4: 0, 
                 5: 0
               }
     }
},
{
  2: {
       "sizes": {
                  2: 0, 
                  3: 0, 
                  4: 3, 
                  5: 0
                }
     }
 },
 {
  3: {
       "sizes": {
                  2: 0, 
                  3: 0, 
                  4: 0, 
                  5: 3
                }
     }
 }
```

**My Current Code**

```
var result = function (data) {
    var stores = {},
        sizes = Object.create(null),
        i = 0;

    data.forEach(function (item) {
        var index = i;

        if (!stores[index]) {
            stores[index] = { sizes: {} };
            Object.keys(sizes).forEach(function (key) {
                stores[index].sizes[key] = 0;
            });
        }

        if (!sizes[item.size]) {
            Object.keys(stores).forEach(function (key) {
                stores[key].sizes[item.size] = 0;
                sizes[item.size] = true;
            });
         }

         stores[index].sizes[item.size] = item.count;

         i++;
   });
   return stores;
}(stocks);

console.log(result);
```

**My Expected Output**

```
{
  0: {
      "sizes": {
                 2: 3, 
                 3: 0, 
                 4: 0, 
                 5: 0
               }
     }
},
{
  1: {
      "sizes": {
                 2: 0, 
                 3: 3, 
                 4: 0, 
                 5: 3
               }
     }
},
{
  2: {
       "sizes": {
                  2: 0, 
                  3: 0, 
                  4: 3, 
                  5: 0
                }
     }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does *"I want to index the object properly"* mean? What is your logic?

Comment: If I put the code you provide in a fiddle it gives me the expected output. [Object Reorganize](https://jsfiddle.net/qsxzrmt2/1/). Can you give me further information on your JavaScript file? How do you pass the stocks object?

Comment: Can you please provider further information on the logic you are trying to implement? What are the indizes of the outer objects? What should be the values for the keys in the sizes object? How are the mapped together? I am also getting a different result from my output. In your listed output and in your expected output you always have 3, but it seems that this should be 5, 4, 4, 5 ?

Comment: You are losing the store id information, even in the expected output. That does not seem right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to get an object structure keyed by store id, and then by size id:

```js
function stocksByStore(stocks) {
  var stores = {}, sizes = [];
  for (var stock of stocks) {
    var storeSizes = (stores[stock.store.id] || 
                      (stores[stock.store.id] = { sizes: {} })).sizes;
    storeSizes[stock.size] = (storeSizes[stock.size] || 0) + stock.count; 
    sizes[stock.size] = 1;
  };
  for (var store in stores) {
    for (var size in sizes) {
      stores[store].sizes[size] = stores[store].sizes[size] || 0;
    }
  }
  return stores;
}

// sample input
var stocks = [{
  "size": "2", "count": 5, "store": { "id": 3, "title": "Belconnen" }
}, {
  "size": "3", "count": 4, "store": { "id": 4, "title": "Canberra" }
}, {
  "size": "4", "count": 4, "store": { "id": 5, "title": "Bankstown" }
}, {
  "size": "5", "count": 5, "store": { "id": 4, "title": "Canberra" }
}];

// conversion
var stores = stocksByStore(stocks); 

// output
console.log(stores);
```

Note that this differs from your expected output, but I think it is more useful to use the `storeId` values as keys of the main object, instead of an incremental number, for which you will not know to which store it refers.